# JOIN 2 select queries FROM ONE TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a single table called journal.
Journal has 4 columns:

1. Date (date)
2. Account(int)
3. Type(varchar(1)  (Can accept chars D or C)
4. Amount(decimal(18,2))

**JOURNAL**

```
Date         Account    Amount    Type
2012-05-31   20001      300       D
2012-05-31   20002      700       C
2012-05-31   20003      600       D
2012-05-31   20004      900       C
```

The type column can only take 2 types of character values: D or C.
So i need a query that will give me 4 columns, such that the resulting columns are:

```
Date        Account       D       C
2012-05-31  200101        300     0
2012-05-31  200102        0       700
2012-05-31  200103        600     0
2012-05-31  200104        0       900
```

with the D and C columns filled with values from Amount, whether they are null or not.

Comment: What database are you using?  Some of them have a PIVOT keyword for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
create table journal
(
    date datetime,
    account int,
    amount money,
    type varchar(1)
)

insert into journal values ('05/31/12', 20001, 300, 'D')
insert into journal values ('05/31/12', 20002, 700, 'C')
insert into journal values ('05/31/12', 20003, 600, 'D')
insert into journal values ('05/31/12', 20004, 900, 'C')

select date
    , account
    , isnull([D], 0) as D
    , isnull([C], 0) as C
from 
(
    select *
    from journal
) x
pivot
(
    sum(amount)
    for type in ([D], [C])
) p

drop table journal
```

See a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66f7d8/1) with a Demo

If you want to join the account names, then you will want to perform a JOIN on that table. See update [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35e54/2) with a demo:

```
select date
    , account
    , name
    , isnull([D], 0) as D
    , isnull([C], 0) as C
from 
(
    select *
    from journal j
    inner join account a
      on j.account = a.id
) x
pivot
(
    sum(amount)
    for type in ([D], [C])
) p
```

Comment: @bluefeet...this is exactly what i want,you just hit the nail on the head.....but one more thing..how do i link to a parent table called Accounts where the account column on journal table is equal to ID on Accounts table, in other to get the account name.

Comment: @froodo I updated my answer, you will want to add a join for the other table.

Comment: @bluefeet...yes but where in this query will i do the join query, as this is the first time am seeing the **PIVOT** syntax or statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE,
       account,
       CASE
         WHEN TYPE = 'D' THEN
          amount
         ELSE
          0
       END D,
       CASE
         WHEN TYPE = 'C' THEN
          amount
         ELSE
          0
       END C TYPE
  FROM JOURNAL
```

Comment: I had to take the word "type" out but then it worked fine.  I just cut and pasted it into the fiddle from above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE [Type] WHEN 'C' THEN [Amount] ELSE 0 END) AS C
    ,SUM(CASE [Type] WHEN 'D' THEN [Amount] ELSE 0 END) AS D
    ,[Date]
    ,[Account]
FROM
    Journal
GROUP BY
    [Date]
    ,[Account]
```

This will sum each value's amount for the date/account combination. You could replace the `SUM` aggregate with any aggregate of your choice (`MIN`, `MAX` etc)